# protoPayload vs jsonPayload in logging

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-stackdriver

The log entries of my app result in jsonPayload while the gae request log entries use protoPayload. Just like in protoPayload, I added a requestId in my logging that shows up in jsonPayload. However, when using the log viewer where "Show entries from same request" action, I don't see my log entries since the filter uses protoPayload.requestId="xyz". I tried to use an or condition with jsonPayload.requestId="xyz" but that didn't help. Ideally I wouldn't even want to manually edit the clause as it will be painful to do everytime. Seems like per the following documentation, the requestId in each of these types of payloads don't map to the same underlying bigquery field.

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/bigquery

There is also a "trace" field directly on the log entry and that is same for all the related logs. However, there is no field called trace to search. Doing a text search does return all the entries. While this works, again the UX is bad as it requires first drilling down to the request log entry, copying the trace value and then doing a query.

So, are there any other options to tie the request log entry with the rest of the app log entries for that request easily?

Comment: Are you searching in the cloud console logs viewer UI, or querying logs exported to BigQuery?

Comment: Just the console logs viewer UI. It seems like when I use appspot.com, then the trace viewer is able to show the additional logs tied to the request and drilling down has a different query which shows all the related entries. However, when I access the app using my custom domain, the related log entries don't show up in the trace and the drill down to logs has a different query that only searches by request_id.

Comment: If you change the field name from "requestId" to anything else, what happens?

Comment: Kevin, please see the answer I posted. I have been able to use "trace" in the log entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a field called "trace" that is on the log entry which works. I think I was confused with the "traceId" within the protoPayload. Note that to get the "trace" field to show up with json payload, the field name should be "logging.googleapis.com/trace"